# Can I make hardware changes to a new laptop before switching it on for the first time?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

Is it ok to replace the 1tb hdd in an alienware 15 r3 laptop with a samsung 860 evo before the laptop is switched on for the first time.

Comment: Clone the hard drive to the new EVO before you boot into the OS, this would be done with clone software that offers a bootable usb version of the clone software, once clone is done swap in the new drive and boot up. You will need a sata to usb adapter to connect the evo to the pc to clone it. Samsung may have free clone software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Of-course, you will need to install the OS etc, and you may well void your warranty.